# Wiring a new ceiling pendant light into a Maestro Plug in Ceiling Rose

Tags: wiring

I am replacing a pendant light and already have a Maestro Plug in Ceiling Rose in situ.  This means that I can slide out the old pendant light (and leave the fixed part of the ceiling rose in place on the ceiling.  When I detach the pendant, and open that (bottom) part of the ceiling rose, there is as expected a terminal for neutral, live and earth.  However the new pendant light I have, has only two wires from the cable , neutral and live.  These end in a terminal (that came with the pendantlight),  and from the terminal there is also an earth which is just attached to the base of the ceiling rose that came with the new pendant.  The problem is, that I was expecting to just wire the new pendant to my Maestro, but I cannot see how the earth works in this case.  I ahve attache photos.  I was expecting to see three wires coming from the light cable itself and in that case it would have been straight forward.  Thanks for any help.  [image: Maestro terminal][image: new light terminal]

Comment: Not quite sure of your problem.  The new light uses a separate ground probably because there is an insulated ground break between two parts or the second part is electrically insulated(plastic) and does not need ground protection, like a metal piece would.

Comment: What is at the other end of the thick black cable that leads out of the bottom of the picture's frame? In my mind, I see a plug there indicating that this is a plug-in light not intended to be hard-wired into the ceiling. Also, what is the grey bit in the first picture? As an American, I'm not familiar with all the UK wiring parts (but I'm learning). Could you replace the blurry photo with a clear one and add a picture of where that grey piece is supposed to be installed?